# Does changing Physics.defaultContactOffset have an important impact on performance?

Tags: unity-game-engine

As usual, the documentation lacking some information we have to gather somewhere else: [Physics.defaultContactOffset](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics-defaultContactOffset.html).

Physics.defaultContactOffset is used by the collision detection system to predictively enforce the contact constraint.

Unity explains you should use 1 unit = 1 meter for physic simulation.

I needed a lot of small spheres and cubes: 10cm width. Thus `0,1` "unit".

What they dont say is that when you're working on a small scale (I'm using objects of 0,1m width = 10cm) you have to change Physics.defaultContactOffset to a smaller value than the default one.

Hence my question: is Physics.defaultContactOffset important for calculations, i.e. if I change this to a very small value, does it have a negative impact on performance?

I have to change it from `0.001` to `0.00001` to get an acceptable collision detection system and I'm worried about a negative impact on performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Unity3D documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsManager.html) on Default Contact Offset:

> Use this to set the distance the collision detection  system uses to
>   generate collision  contacts. The value must be positive, and **if set
>   too close to zero, it can cause jitter**. This is set to 0.01 by
>   default. Colliders only generate collision contacts if their distance
>   is less than the sum of their contact offset values.

So we can assume the physics engine is calculating distances between colliders and checking if the distance counts as a collision or not. I don't think it matters so much for performance as the calculation is done anyway.

With all this being said, Unity3d physics engine doesn't really do well with tiny objects, so it's better if you scale the spheres up to 1 unit, and scale everything else to compensate. You will most likely run into issues with these tiny colliders.

Comment: May I ask you to give the link where you found that, because with the direct link on the Physics.defaultContactOffset there's nothing about that. And for the tiny thing, I have to change that because of Physics scale problem (mass calculation was nonsense with my 1mx1m diameter ball so it's much better with 10cmx10cm right now... and I hope you're wrong but I'm a bit worried about that, it's the 4th time I'm trying from a brand new project with different scale + different "basic" object made under blender...)

Comment: Sure, you can find the information here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsManager.html

Comment: You can adjust all general physics settings in the Physics Manager or just for one object by changing its RigidBody settings to make the simulation more correct for your game. Objects imported from blender usually need to have the scale adjusted. I had a similar problem in my recent project.

Comment: This post should be helpful: https://answers.unity.com/questions/140988/how-do-you-change-measurement-units-in-unity.html where Joshua wrote: "Units of distance and scale are meaningless and relative to nothing. Call them meters, inches or lightyears, it affects nothing.

The only thing that it does affect if force and velocity calculations by the physics engine. But since you control this all you have to do is take it into account. The only hardcoded place where you need to adjust the force is under gravity settings..."