# Unity2D OverlapCollider detects an collider when its not overlapping at all

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
ContactFilter2D _contactFilter = new ContactFilter2D();
_contactFilter.SetLayerMask(LayerMask.GetMask("Box"));

List<Collider2D> _overlapColliders = new List<Collider2D>();

int _collidersCount = hitboxCollider.OverlapCollider(_contactFilter, _overlapColliders);
if (_collidersCount)
{
    Debug.Log("I detected an collider when its not true at all!");
}
```

Here a screenshot of my case -> [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q53s.png)

As the title said, I can't find a solution at all, maybe I'm missing something.
Thx, and sorry for my bad question.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that "Default Contact Offset" is the cause.
Here link related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53101873/13162558